# Regular Expression to stop after first find

Tags: .net, regex

if I have the following text:

```
some text
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
This can be any text
GO

other text
GO

more text
```

I would like to only match

```
CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]  
any text that is here
GO
```

using Regular Expression.  What I have tried so far fails and gives me everything up to the last GO. I would like to stop after finding the first occurence of GO.

This is what I tried:

```
CREATE DATABASE[^<>]*^(GO)+?
```

I understand why it does not work, but don't know how to fix it.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Make it ungreedy http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/607837-want-regular-expression-stop-first-occurrence-word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
CREATE DATABASE+([\s\S]*?)+GO
```

or still shorter

```
CREATE DATABASE[\s\S]*?GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Append a `?` to your regex to make it non greedy

http://www.lbsharp.com/wordpress/index.php/2007/02/19/net-regular-expressions/

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
CREATE DATABASE \[(.+?)\]
```

Comment: BTW, I used this tool to test out the answer: http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm

Comment: I run it in Expresso to test it, but it returns up to the second GO. I have set it to multiline. Maybe there is something else I am doing wrong???

Comment: I didn't eyeball the result closely enough. The revised answer should do it and capture the database name.

Comment: Great, it leaves out the first GO, but I can live with that. Now, I will try to understand how this works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah no, this won't work, it does not take the text in between CREATE DATABASE and the first GO.

Comment: Okay, if I understand you correctly, you need this:              `CREATE DATABASE \[(.+?)\](.*$\n.*\n)GO`

Comment: That should capture the database names and whatever is being fed to create it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, but this does not work either. It does not return anything.  BTW, the text CREATE DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] is static.  It is what is between that and the first GO that can change.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, this works for me (where **dot matches new line** is set, if necessary)

```
CREATE DATABASE.*?GO
```

See it tested at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) with this permalink I created for it: http://rubular.com/r/2KsBrnSGhC

Comment: I just noticed you've answered it, but mine's shorter, so I'll leave it up :-)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me make mine a bit shorter. BTW, I haven't look how to set the dot matches a new line in my context (TFS Build Template), so I'll stick to what I have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm terrible with regex, so if you're in a .Net environment, try using this great addin from MS:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/55c24bf1-2636-4f94-831d-28db8505ce00